# passing a variable (containing GPS co-ordinates) from arduino through serial input into a url request in Raspberry pi in python

Tags: python-requests

hello  guys i would like a very quick help.
I'm very new to python and this is related to my college project with the Raspberry pi

i want to acquire data from a GPS module connected to the arduino ( i did clean up the data the way i want it) through a serial port and pass it onto a variable which is to be passed to a URL request for an XML from Open street maps.(I used the Python Requests package )
I have successfully parsed the xml and got the result by manually setting the url

here is an example link from wiki.openstreetmap.org

http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=11.54,48.14,11.543,48.145

I have to pass on the value (in this example ) "11.54,48.14,11.543,48.145" 
which i believe is a tuple?
please help !

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data from Arduino to Raspberry Pi using serial communication in Python
Read about **pyserial** library.